# Referencing a variable after separating it from a list

Tags: python

```
input = "12345_usa_wool_10x10_100_80.jpg"

def CleanData(input):
    data = input.split('_')

    sku = data[0]
    country = data[1].capitalize()
    material = data[2].capitalize()
    size = data[3]
    retail_price = data[4]
    sale_price = data[5]

CleanData(input)
print (sku)
print (country)
```

I'm getting

```
NameError: name 'sku' is not defined
```

I tried to store all the values in the list I created to easily reference back to them later.

Such as if they wanted total savings I could then later make something like

```
def Saving()
    total_saving = retail_price-sale_price
    return total_saving
```

So I can later have a final output of something like:

```
print (sku+" "+country+" "+sale_price+" "+Saving())
```

I'm a beginner and self-learner so I figured this isn't too hard of a problem but I don't know how to have sku,country,material, etc. be able to be referenced publicly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sku` is defined in the `CleanData` function only, it does not have scope outside of that function.

I'd recommend using a `dict` object instead. E.g.,

```
def parseData(input):
    data = input.split('_')
    d = {}
    d['sku'] = data[0]
    d['country'] = data[1].capitalize()
    d['material'] = data[2].capitalize()
    d['size'] = data[3]
    d['retail_price'] = data[4]
    d['sale_price'] = data[5]
    return d

myData = parseData(input)
print(myData['sku'])
print(myData['country'])
```

You can also directly construct the `dict`:

```
def parseData(input):
    data = input.split('_')
    d = {'sku': data[0],
         'country': data[1].capitalize(),
         'material': data[2].capitalize(),
         'size': data[3],
         'retail_price': data[4],
         'sale_price': data[5]}
    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is python *scope*, `sku`, and all the other variables assigned in the function, are local to the function.  If you want them to be global, then mark them as such:

```
def CleanData(input):
    data = input.split('_')

    global sku
    sku = data[0]

.... and so on
```

However, it is generally not a good idea to use global variables in this way.  We want our functions to be *encapsulated* so that they can be used in many programs.  The problem with using globals is that you have to know that the name is not going to be used for something else in the program.  If you need to reuse the code across programs then that will break.

The solution is to return some sort of *container*.  For example it could be a dictionary, a list, or a tuple.  Here is an example using a tuple:

```
def CleanData(input):
    data = input.split('_')

    # sku, country, material, size, retail_price, sale_price 
    return (data[0], 
            data[1].capitalize(),
            data[2].capitalize(),
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5])

sku, country, material, size, retail_price, sale_price = CleanData(input)
print (sku)
print (country)
```

You could probably simplify this further by just returning `data`.  In addition you might wish to test `len(data)` to ensure you have the correct number of fields.